# Passing payload to endpoint

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to create a POST API using (wso2 API manager1.9) which will accept a request as JSON payload and using payload factory mediator change the requested payload and pass new payload to back-end proxy to get the response.

Payload for POST API:

```
{
        "id" :"8888822",  
       "l_name" : "aiiii",
       "f_name" : "lllla"
}
```

2. PAYLOAD to back-end proxy:

I need to append JSON payload within   JSON payload  and send to back-end. Could you please let me know how to achieve this? I have tried with payload factory mediator and passed as below.

```
<input>
<newParam>
    {
       "sm_id" :"8888822",  
       "l_name" : "aiiii",
       "f_name" : "lllla"      
}
</newParam>
</input>

<payloadFactory>
      <format>
          <input>
            <newParam>
                 "id" :"$1",  
                "lname" : "$2",
                "fname" : "$3"
            </newParam>
          </input>
      <args>
           <arg expression="//input/newParam/id">
           <arg expression="//input/newParam/lname">
           <arg expression="//input/newParam/fname">
      </arg></arg></args>
</payloadFactory>
```

But it is not working, could you please let me know what is the issue in this or any change required if any.

I really appreciate your quick response on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the Json values into properties with :

```
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="id" expression="json-eval($.id)" scope="default" type="STRING">
```

etc.

Then inside payload :

```
<payloadFactory>
      <format>
          <input>
            <newParam>
                 { 
                   "sm_id" :"$1",  
                   "lname" : "$2",
                   "fname" : "$3"
                 }
            </newParam>
          </input>
       </format>
      <args>
           <arg expression="get-property('id')">
           <arg expression="get-property('lname')">
           <arg expression="get-property('fname')">
      </arg></arg></arg></args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Comment: You might need <arg expression="get-property('id')" evaluator="json">